# Is it possible for my website to execute requests on other websites?

Tags: node.js, post, request, backend, csrf

There's a website I use that's not mine. On the website, I can view a bunch of data through a tedious process: using a series of POST requests, I view the data, and then based on the data I saw, I submit data of my own (again, using a `<form action=POST>`).

I'd like to make a website that allows me (or anybody else with an account on this site) to view all the data at once, and then submit the data. So essentially, I want to serve the data from the site from *my* backend and simulate the POSTs, essentially acting as a middleman. Is this possible? The forms have CSRF tokens and a bunch of fields, but I was thinking that I could simply *request* these tokens from the backend on behalf of the user and run my POST requests from there.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is possible. But the other website can blocked POST requests from your site (server).

Comment: If I'm executing requests on behalf of the user, how could it tell my server and the user apart in a robust way (i.e. not disallowing IP address switches)?